# extracting string between two regular expressions "|" patterns

Tags: string, shell, extract, cat

I want to extract all the strings between `gi|` and `|`. The position of the string is consistent in all the lines.

I am trying this one:

```
cat ERR594382_second_cat.test | sed -n '/gi\|/,/\|/p'
```

But, it is not working.

Here is a  head of my file :

```
head ERR594382_second_cat.test 
ERR594382.28316455_3_6_1    gi|914605561|ref|WP_050599988.1|    22  54  67  99  4.03e-15    77.0    100.000 33  0   0   225971;1306953  Bacteria    Erythrobacter citreus;Erythrobacter citreus LAMA 915    ribonuclease D [Erythrobacter citreus]
ERR594382.28316455_65_2_3   gi|914605561|ref|WP_050599988.1|    13  46  11  44  2.15e-17    82.8    100.000 34  0   0   225971;1306953  Bacteria    Erythrobacter citreus;Erythrobacter citreus LAMA 915    ribonuclease D [Erythrobacter citreus]
ERR594382.28316459_1_1_2    gi|1270336953|gb|PHR32068.1|    8   53  863 903 6.98e-08    56.6    63.043  46  12  1   2024840 Bacteria    Methylophaga sp.    phosphohydrolase [Methylophaga sp.]
ERR594382.28316464_2_2_3    gi|705244733|gb|AIW56710.1| 2   33  145 176 5.76e-12    67.8    93.750  32  2   0   340016  Viruses uncultured virus    ribonucleotide reductase, partial [uncultured virus]
ERR594382.28316464_53_5_5   gi|1200458341|gb|OUV73944.1|    1   31  557 587 9.54e-11    64.3    80.645  31  6   0   1986721 Bacteria    Flavobacteriales bacterium TMED123  hypothetical protein CBC83_04720 [Flavobacteriales bacterium TMED123]
ERR594382.28316465_3_3_2    gi|787065740|dbj|BAR36435.1|    1   46  204 249 5.55e-10    63.2    58.696  46  19  0   1407671 Viruses uncultured Mediterranean phage uvMED    hypothetical protein [uncultured Mediterranean phage uvMED]
ERR594382.28316465_67_4_3   gi|787065740|dbj|BAR36435.1|    2   34  224 256 1.31e-07    55.1    66.667  33  11  0   1407671 Viruses uncultured Mediterranean phage uvMED    hypothetical protein [uncultured Mediterranean phage uvMED]
ERR594382.28316466_18_6_3   gi|1200295886|gb|OUU17830.1|    1   33  92  124 1.73e-12    70.1    100.000 33  0   0   1986638 Bacteria    Alphaproteobacteria bacterium TMED37    hypothetical protein CBB97_21775 [Candidatus Endolissoclinum sp. TMED37]
ERR594382.28316470_37_1_1   gi|787067413|dbj|BAR37857.1|    16  43  60  87  1.94e-09    58.9    96.429  28  1   0   1407671 Viruses uncultured Mediterranean phage uvMED    terminase large subunit [uncultured Mediterranean phage uvMED]
ERR594382.28316474_2_5_1    gi|1219813777|gb|ASN63501.1|    1   33  62  94  3.55e-12    64.3    81.818  33  6   0   340016  Viruses uncultured
```

Comment: ([Useless Use of Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#UUOC_(Useless_Use_Of_Cat)))

Comment: `sed 's/.*gi|\([^|]\+\)|.*/\1/g' ERR594382_second_cat.test`?

Comment: `cut -f2 -d'|' ERR594382_second_cat.test`?

Comment: Dear Biffen, thank you for your quick response. The first one is not working , because it prints all the lines , but the second one  looks that it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep` or / `pcregrep` (in case of using macOS) with this:

```
pcregrep -o "gi\|\K.+?(?=\|)" file
```

or with:

```
grep -oP "gi\|\K.+?(?=\|)" file
```

The `\K` can be read as excluding everything to the left before it and return only the right part `.+`, and then the `.+?(?=\|)` match any characters until `|` is found.

The easiest way if only your delimiter is fixed could be with `cut`:

```
cut -f2 -d"|" file
```